# The notification posted automatically when the image anchor in another scene is anchored

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

In my project, there are 3 scenes in Reality File. I created a button to control the notification, when the button is clicked, the notification posted according to the image anchor.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
   @State private var Scene1 = try! Experience1.loadScene1()
   @State private var Scene2 = try! Experience1.loadScene2()
   @State private var Scene3 = try! Experience1.loadScene3()

   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
       ARViewContainer(arView: $arView, Scene1: $Scene1, Scene2: $Scene2, Scene3: $Scene3)
       Button("Replay") {
          if arView.scene.anchors.count > 0 {
             if arView.scene.anchors[0].isAnchored {
                Scene1.notifications.replay.post()
             } else if arView.scene.anchors[1].isAnchored {
                Scene2.notifications.replay.post()
             } else if arView.scene.anchors[2].isAnchored {
                Scene3.notifications.replay.post()
             } 
          }
       }
       }
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    @Binding var Scene1: Experience1.Scene1
    @Binding var Scene2: Experience1.Scene2
    @Binding var Scene3: Experience1.Scene3
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
            arView.scene.anchors.append(Scene1)
            arView.scene.anchors.append(Scene2)
            arView.scene.anchors.append(Scene3)
        }
        
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

**The problem:** When the image anchor in Scene1 is anchored and the button is clicked, the notifications in another scenes sometimes posted. Can I fix it?

P.S. I created the notifications to control the action of 3D Model in Reality File.